# Deploying Chiliproject to Dreamhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dreamhost, chiliproject

Having some issues deploying this.  I've tried to deploy it twice now.  Here's what I've done so far....

Installed the gems and versions required on the [install page](https://www.chiliproject.org/projects/chiliproject/wiki/Installation):

```
gem install -v=2.3.5 rails
gem install -v=1.0.1 rack
gem install -v=0.8.7 rake
gem install -v=0.4.2 i18n
```

Downloaded the package:

```
git clone git://github.com/chiliproject/chiliproject.git
cd chiliproject
git checkout stable
```

Had to find and set bundle since it wasn't in my path:

```
BUNDLE="/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/bundle"
```

Put my database info into database.yml:

And then started the bundle stuff:

```
$BUNDLE install --without=postgres rmagick
$BUNDLE exec rake generate_session_store
```

The last command got the error:

```
rake aborted!
can't activate rails (= 2.3.5, runtime), already activated rails-2.3.12. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
```

So I changed 2.3.12 to 2.3.5 in the Gemfile and carried on:

```
RAIL_ENV=production $BUNDLE exec rake db:migrate
```

Then I got an error on this command too:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
undefined method `autoload_paths' for #<Rails::Configuration:0x68a68dbb82c0>
/home/USERNAME/DOMAIN/public/config/environment.rb:44
```

I tried commenting out line 44 there, but then it threw another error `undefined method`convert_to_without_fallback_on_iso_8859_1' for class `Class'` so I didn't want to play around with it further.  **Note** this only happened the second time I tried to deploy it.  The first time I tried db:migrate succeeded (and I checked there was not data already in the DB).

**So for the second try I am stuck here :-( **

But this is what happened the first time after db:migrate succeded....

```
RAILS_ENV=production $BUNDLE exec rake redmine:load_default_data
```

With the last command however it failed saying permission denied for mysql 'user'@'173.236.128.0/255.255.128.0' and I was like WTF is it trying to connect to a network as if it were a host?

So I moved on, copied my configuration file and environment files in.  Changed/added these lines:

```
# Uncomment below to force Rails into production mode when
# you don't control web/app server and can't set it the proper way
 ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'

# Specifies gem version of Rails to use when vendor/rails is not present
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.5'# unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION

if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'production'  # don't bother on dev
  ENV['GEM_PATH'] = '/home/USERNAME/.gems' + ':/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8'
end
```

Then made this stuff writable and restarted Passenger:

```
chmod -R 777 files log tmp public/plugin_assets/
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

**Sorry for the wall of text**, is anybody able to shine some light on something I've done wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: So this is all wrong, here's how I got it working**

```
rm ~/.gem*
gem install bundler

PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin

cd ~
git clone git://github.com/chiliproject/chiliproject.git
cd chiliproject
git checkout stable

cp * ../example.com/ -R
cd ../example.com

# Make sure database is working

bundle install --without postgres rmagick test
bundle exec rake generate_session_store

RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate

# No output is no good, check database.yml

RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake redmine:load_default_data
```

Or see this: https://gist.github.com/1127306

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current ChiliProject stable releases (2.x) require the use of bundler. Thus the answer by Slotos is incorrect here. gen install doesn't work anymore, we NEED bundler.

Also, we require Rails 2.3.12 now. You won't get any working results if you arbitrarily edit files. On certain platforms, you need to adapt the [Gemfile](https://github.com/chiliproject/chiliproject/blob/stable/Gemfile) (e.g. when using Ruby 1.8.6 or for certain versions of ImageMagick). For the currently suggested setup using Ruby 1.8.7 or REE, you don't need to adapt anything though.

For installing the dependencies of the currently stable ChiliProject 2.x releases, you basically need to do the following:

At first you need to make sure that the directory where gem binaries re installed to is in your `$PATH`. This can be temporarily be achieved by running this (in your case)

```
export PATH=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin:$PATH
```

Then you need to install the bundler gem and instruct it to install all dependencies

```
gem install bundler
bundle install --without rmagick postgres test # in your case
```

What is really strange in your case is that rake seems to try to enable Rails 2.3.5. It should not do that (and doesn't unless you have changed certain files). I strongly recommend to start with a new clean source tree and don't change any arbitrary files.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I was stuck with a passenger error saying it couldn't find a gem, didn't say which one though.  I ran the commands you said and it started working yay!  Here's the list of commands I used that made it work https://gist.github.com/1127306  Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix up `gem install` commands with bundler package management. You will get unexpected results from doing so.

If you really want to use bundler - add all the gems you want into a [Gemfile](http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html).
Otherwise just omit it.

Quick search for "bundler chiliproject" lead me to [chiliproject-gemfile](https://github.com/finnlabs/chiliproject-gemfile). Apparently it have been merged into unstable already.

Comment: Thank you thank you, I dropped gem install and started using bundler only... passenger said it couldn't find a gem tho... doing it --without test seemed to work tho.